# BlobInfo object from a BlobKey created using blobstore.create_gs_key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

I am converting code away from the deprecated files api.

I have the following code that works fine in the SDK server but fails in production. Is what I am doing even correct? If yes what could be wrong, any ideas how to troubleshoot it?

```
# Code earlier writes the file bs_file_name. This works fine because I can see the file
# in the Cloud Console.
bk = blobstore.create_gs_key( "/gs" + bs_file_name)
assert(bk)
if not isinstance(bk,blobstore.BlobKey):
    bk = blobstore.BlobKey(bk)
assert isinstance(bk,blobstore.BlobKey)
# next line fails here in production only
assert(blobstore.get(bk))  # <----------- blobstore.get(bk) returns None
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error, I get None back. I will clarify.

Comment: not that it should matter but, what happens if you remove `bk = blobstore.BlobKey(bk)` line (also, all asserts except for the last one)?

Comment: I have tried that too, it did not make a difference. I suspect a permissions problem but I want at least to get some confirmation that my approach is supposed to work. I am converting from the deprecated, but working very well, files API and want to change as little as possible.

Comment: It's supposed to return a blob_key, are you able to add new files/folders to gcs from google cloud console? I bet it's a permissions issue, does happen a lot, it mostly fixes itself with time and errors are undocumented and non-deterministic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, as per the documentation, you can't get a BlobInfo object for GCS files.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage

> Note: Once you obtain a blobKey for the GCS object, you can pass it around, serialize it, and otherwise use it interchangeably anywhere you can use a blobKey for objects stored in Blobstore. This allows for usage where an app stores some data in blobstore and some in GCS, but treats the data otherwise identically by the rest of the app. **(However, BlobInfo objects are currently not available for GCS objects.)**

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I read this section carefully and do not recall the highlighted but is there indeed. I am wondering when exactly it was added :-)

Comment: Yep caught me out too. One slight exception to this that might be worth mentioning. If you use the BlobStore API to upload the file to a GCS bucket, you get a BlobKey for this which you CAN use to get a BlobInfo. This is because the BlobStore API creates the BlobInfo. In this instance I store both the original BlobKey and the GCS object name so I can get the BlobInfo. It's worth noting that this BlobKey is not the same as the one you get from create_gs_key().

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this exact same issue today and it feels very much like a bug within the blobstore api when using google cloud storage.

Rather than leveraging the blobstore api I made use of the google cloud storage client library. The library can be downloaded here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/download

To access a file on GCS:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs

with gcs.open(GCSFileName) as f:
    blob_content = f.read()
    print blob_content
```

Comment: Of course one can do this but I already have a lot of source code that uses BlobInfos everywhere and wanted to migrate making the minimum number of changes.

Comment: @gae123 I totally agree, with you but so far my findings are showing that this isn't possible. If you find otherwise please update this thread.

Answer (score 0):

It sucks that GAE has different behaviours when using blobInfo in local mode or the production environment, it took me a while to find out that, but a easy solution is that:

You can use a blobReader to access the data when you have the blob_key.

```
def getBlob(blob_key):
  logging.info('getting blob('+blob_key+')')

  with blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key) as f:
    data_list = []
    chunk = f.read(1000)
    while chunk != "":
      data_list.append(chunk)
      chunk = f.read(1000)

    data = "".join(data_list)

  return data`
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass