# Blobstore in production does not get BlobKey (while in dev_appserver it does)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I've got a process that fetches an image from a given URL and saves it to Google Cloud Storage and retrieves a serving url. Now, my understanding (from the documentation I've read) is that I must also create a blob in the process that references the GCS file. If my understanding is incorrect, please let me know.

The handler that fetches the image and tries to save it is:

```
img_request = urlfetch.fetch(img_url)
    if img_request.status_code == 200:
        img_title               = hashlib.sha1(img_url).hexdigest()
        img_content             = img_request.content
        img_type                = img_request.headers['content-type']
        cloud_storage_filename  = '/images/%s/%s' % (self.source_name, img_title)

        blobstore_filename      = '/gs%s' % cloud_storage_filename
        blobstore_key           = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)

        cloud_storage_file      = gcs.open(filename=cloud_storage_filename, mode='w', content_type=img_type)
        cloud_storage_file.write(img_content)
        cloud_storage_file.close()

        # If I print blobstore_key at this stage, I am getting a result here.
        blobstore_key           = blobstore.get(blobstore_key).key()
        blobstore_serving_url   = images.get_serving_url(blobstore_key)

        # Structured Property to be part of a Datastore Model
        img_model = data_model.Image(
            s_source_url    = img_url,
            k_blob_key      = blobstore_key,
            s_serving_url   = blobstore_serving_url
        )
        return img_model
```

This works fine on the dev_appserver, however, in production it raises the following error:

```
   blobstore_key           = blobstore.get(blobstore_key).key()
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Why is this error being raised in Production and not on the dev_appserver? As if the key is not being generated in the first place...

As I have commented in the code, when I print the `blobstore_key` before calling `blobstore.get(blobstore_key).key()`, it does print out a key, so it's working fin until there. The problem is, presumably, when I call `blobstore.get()` on the key, it gets `None`... why???

Or am I doing something completely wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You are probably hitting the same issue I raised with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287709/blobinfo-object-from-a-blobkey-created-using-blobstore-create-gs-key    For now, I gave up my transition until this is fully clarified.

Comment: @gae123 yes, I found your post and it helped me solve the issue for my use case. Since all I needed was to call `get_serving_url()` on a file uploaded to GCS, according to the documentation I needed to get a `blobstore.BlobKey` to pass it to `get_serving_url`, so essentially what I did was to call `blobstore.BlobKey(blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename))` and this returns a `BlobKey` object which I can then use to call `get_serving_url`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

Substituted:

```
blobstore_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)
```

With:

```
blobstore_key = blobstore.BlobKey(blobstore_key)
```

Answer (score 7):

`blobstore.get()` is a synonym for `BlobInfo.get()`, and a note on [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) page says:

> However, BlobInfo objects are currently not available for GCS objects.

This would explain why your `blobstore.get()` returns `None`.

Also, aren't you expecting to receive the same result from these two lines?

```
blobstore_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)
blobstore_key = blobstore.get(blobstore_key).key()
```

Comment: They don't return the same thing. One is a GS key whereas the other is a BlobKey. I need the BlobKey to get the serving_url to actually serve the image.

Comment: @MichaelGradek On the linked page there is a note: "Once you obtain a blobKey for the GCS object, you can pass it around, serialize it, and otherwise use it interchangeably anywhere you can use a blobKey for objects stored in Blobstore. This allows for usage where an app stores some data in blobstore and some in GCS, but treats the data otherwise identically by the rest of the app."

In the example they present they use `blobstore.fetch_data()` to get the data from the GS.

Answer (score 2):

[BlobInfo object from a BlobKey created using blobstore.create_gs_key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287709/blobinfo-object-from-a-blobkey-created-using-blobstore-create-gs-key) seems to partially answer my doubts of why it does not work in production. However, how do I get the servng_url for a image then?

Comment: You don't need a BlobInfo. The blobkey from blobstore.create_gs_key can be passed to images.get_serving_url. However you should note that images.get_serving_url only works on images. For example, it won't work on svg files which render images

Answer (score 0):

It sucks that GAE has different behaviours when using blobInfo in local mode or the production environment, it took me a while to find out that, but a easy solution is that:

You can use a blobReader to access the data when you have the blob_key

```
def getBlob(blob_key):
  logging.info('getting blob('+blob_key+')')

  with blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key) as f:
    data_list = []
    chunk = f.read(1000)
    while chunk != "":
      data_list.append(chunk)
      chunk = f.read(1000)

    data = "".join(data_list)

  return data`
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass